# Firefox text 1px lower than chrome and ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

This is driving me crazy. Firefox text is 1px lower than in chrome and ie. It's not a margin or padding issue on html or body, tried that. Doesn't seem to be a rounding issue either. Here is an image:

[image]

First "Hello" is Firefox 13, Second "Hello" is IE9 and "Hello World" is Chrome.

Here is the code (pretty simple):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine and chrome frame -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Pixel Bug?</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html{
            font-size: 100%;
        }
        body{
            font-size: 1em;
            line-height: 1.5;
            background: white url('images/grid16.png') -4px -6px;
        }
        p{
            margin: 1.5em 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World 2!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it just a bug? What is going on here? I don't want a FireFox only work around, I just want to understand why this is happening.

**EDIT:**

Upon further research it seems to be a rendering bug, but it still confuses me. For example, the height of the text should be 24px. Which shouldn't really cause rounding errors that would cause this. Yet, if I change the line-height to 23px explicitly it lines up. I have no idea why.

**EDIT2:** Possible reason? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=442139

**EDIT3:** Lines up using a 20px font and 40px line height. Makes me think this is just so rendering bug. It's sucks cause 16/24 is pretty standard :/

Comment: I had this issue with a font-face font and could only work around this by simple setting the font-size smaller in safari (was a safari only bug). dirty workaround, but it made the client happy

Comment: It's probably the different font smoothing techniques used by the various browsers/OSes. Trying to match on a pixel level is a fool's errand.

Comment: it may have to do with hardware acceleration. Try disabling hardware acceleration and see if anything changes (under options->advanced)

Comment: @Fidrizers http://jsfiddle.net/MfDkc/ Hmmm. Works in jsfiddle. Makes me think it is in fact some strange rendering bug.

Answer (score 2):

See my earlier answer here::
[CSS white-space and list-style-image do not stack in Firefox 11+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10996086/1085285)

You are not using reset.css thus creating problems

[Here you can find many links for the reset.css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116754/1085285)
 Reason for using reset.css is because it will make all user-agent(browser) css to a base settings, so that they don't look different in different browsers.

**Edit::**
As the OP used the reset.css . I can't reproduce the issue. So the other reasons might be

- Font rendering issue of different broser engine. No particuar fix [Read more](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-can-i-make-fonts-render-the-same-way-across-different-web-browsers)
- Issue with hardware. [Joel talks about it in his blog.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html)

Also, I agree with what @steveax said.

**Edit 2::**
  If you want to go in depth about it .

- Raise a bug
- [Try tuning your browser yourself](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/23/blurry-fonts-in-firefox-try-anti-aliasing-tuner/)

Comment: @Burning the Codeigniter Yes I have. Upon further searching it seems to be a rendering bug, but it still confuses me. For example, the height of the text should be 24px. Which shouldn't really cause rounding errors that would cause this. Yet, if I change the line-height to 23px explicitly it lines up. I have no idea why.

Comment: @PeachPassion Which reset did you use?

Comment: IMHO, a CSS reset is a shotgun approach to problem solving.  What I'd like to know is which specific CSS property needs to be "reset" in order to make this problem go away?  Somehow though, I think this is more font/browser related than anything to do with CSS.

Comment: Please stop thinking CSS reset is a magic wand that solves everything. If adding CSS reset helps you, find out what's the problematic CSS property and post it as an answer; otherwise don't post anything.